# Do I use commas before the word "to" in the following sentence:

Tags: prepositions

The JP-8 pipelines included 7.4 miles of parallel 10-inch pipelines from the Navy's transfer pump house manifold to the custody transfer to the Anderson Air Force Base.

Comment: Only one comma before _to_, please. And only if you put a comma before the word _from_.

Comment: I think adding a comma before the word 'from' slows down the sentence. And which 'to' are you referring to - the one after 'manifold' or the the one after 'transfer'?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Whichever one you were referring to. The sentence, unpunctuated as it is, is multiply ambiguous, and the writer must supply the disambiguating intonation with punctuation. Incidentally, there is no speed to written sentences. People read at their own rates, and many prefer clarity and precision when dealing with technical details. No matter how slow the sentence seems to the writer.

Comment: Hahaha....I agree that the sentence is ambiguous, but I’m not allowed to rearrange it, or add words, which is infuriating!  In regards to your no-speed-to-sentence statement, I partially disagree.  You are right that everyone reads at their own rates and that everyone prefers clarity and precision when they read, that’s a given, but sentences can be ‘slowed-down’ by punctuation.  Take the next sentence, just as an example:
 You can’t tell me that you’re not, for a split second, slowing, down, when, you, get, to, the, commas, in, this, sentence!    ;)  j/k

Comment: You, can, pro-, nounce, e, ver, y, syl, la, ble, this, way, if, you, like. It's the same intonation as counting: _1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..._. But nobody does, because it adds nothing. But some intonation is necessary, and a good writer uses enough commas to supply them. As [Strunk and White](http://chronicle.com/article/50-Years-of-Stupid-Grammar/25497) might have put it, in their famous helpful style: "Use enough commas, but not too many."

Comment: We will have to agree to disagree. ;)  Strunk and E.B. White are right, as is Stephen King, who mentioned their rule in his book A Memoir: On Writing. I'm not comma savvy, nor am I a writing genius, especially when it comes to editing lengthy technical documents.  I consequently must rely on people like you, or my boss who isn’t here, to steer my less-than-satisfactory-comma brain in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks to you, I think I know what to do for the sentence I asked about, and that is to add a comma before the last ‘to’, but not before the word ‘from’, because I don’t like it, because it sounds funny to me.  Thanks again for your help, John!

Answer (score 2):

I'd be tempted to reorganise the sentence slightly in order to avoid the `'to the'` -> `'to the'` pair.

> The JP-8 pipelines included 7.4 miles of parallel 10-inch pipelines
>   from the Navy's transfer pump house manifold to the Anderson Air Force
>   Base, via the custody transfer.

I think it makes it clearer that the 10-inch pipes go between the manifold and Anderson, rather than possibly just between the manifold and the transfer *(from someone who doesn't know how close together a manifold and a transfer normally are - but I'm guessing they are not that far apart)*

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to reorganize it.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a comma after manifold and a comma after transfer.

" The JP-8 pipelines included 7.4 miles of parallel 10-inch pipelines from the Navy's transfer pump house manifold, to the custody transfer, to the Anderson Air Force Base."

The commas are separating the places the JP-8 pipelines extend.

Comment: Why, though? Can you explain why it's necessary to put commas there? [Good answers explain why and how.](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)